# PHP Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method

Tags: php, arrays, callback, array-filter

I originally have this big array that i get from my database in a shortened version:

```
$arreglo =Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2600,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2602,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "2" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2603,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "3" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2648,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "4" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2653,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "5" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2655,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "6" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2698,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "7" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2722,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "8" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2741,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "9" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2743,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "10" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2744,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "11" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2745,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "12" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2763,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "13" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2778,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "14" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2780,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "15" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2782,
            "R1" => 1
        ),

    "16" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2607,
            "R1" => 2
        ),

    "17" => Array
        (
            "concurso" => 2609,
            "R1" => 2
        )
);
```

It goes on until the "R1" element value is 56.

So i want to separate each set of values of R1, for example, just when R1 equals 1, i store each value of "concurso" in an array called "$concursos" by using the following function:

```
function category($var)
{
    return (is_array($var) && $var['R1'] == 1);
}
$current=array_filter($arreglo,"category");
```

Everything works fine until now, since, when R1 = 1, i get only that list of concursos when R1 = 1 as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2600
    [1] => 2602
    [2] => 2603
    [3] => 2648
    [4] => 2653
    [5] => 2655
    [6] => 2698
    [7] => 2722
    [8] => 2741
    [9] => 2743
    [10] => 2744
    [11] => 2745
    [12] => 2763
    [13] => 2778
    [14] => 2780
    [15] => 2782
)
```

The problem is that, if i want to make this again for the following numbers where R1=2,3,...56 inside a for loop, then, instead of specifying ==1, i would set ==$currentR1, in the function like this:

```
function category($var)
    {
        return (is_array($var) && $var['R1'] == $currentR1);
    }
    $current=array_filter($arreglo,"category");
```

Now the problem is that if i try to put an argument, the call of the function fails, how can i specify here a parameter?

I have tried, for example,

```
$current=array_filter($repeticiones,array('category',$l));
```

and it fails warning me

Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method in myScript.php on line X

Then how can i specify the parameter?

Comment: `array('category',$l)` --- what did you want to express with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function like this:

```
$r = 2;
$current = array_filter($arreglo, function($var) use ($r){
                                                 // ^ import variable to the closure scope
    return (is_array($var) && $var['R1'] == $r);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that returns another function that you can pass to `array_filter()`:

```
function categoryFunction($someVar)
{
    return function($var) use ($someVar) {
        return (is_array($var) && $var['R1'] == $someVar);
    };
}

$current=array_filter($arreglo, categoryFunction($l));
```

Comment: @zerkms Thanks. I mix up JavaScript and PHP sometimes :)

Comment: honestly those were the same mistakes I've made as well: missed a semicolon and originally left the nested function name :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function, something like this :

```
for($r = 1; $r < 56; $r++){
    $current=array_filter($arreglo,function ($var) use ($r) { return ($var['R1'] == $r); });
    ...do something with $current...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me, creating a callable function in a less-anonymous way is more intuitive:

```
$category = function ($var)
    {
        return (is_array($var) && $var['R1'] == $currentR1);
    };

    $current=array_filter($arreglo, $category);
```